Not able to pause the video
let video = document.querySelector(".reel video");

video.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("Video clicked"); // Add console log to check if the event listener is triggered
    video.pause();
    video.style.height = "0%";
    video.style.width = "0%";
    document.exitFullscreen();
    console.log("Video paused"); // Add console log to check if video is paused
});

I want to pause the video by clicking on the video anywhere on the screen.
Every line of code is working properly, I checked all the lines but I am not able to pause the video.

Try this:
let video = document.querySelector(".reel video");

if (video) {
    video.addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("Video clicked");
        if (!video.paused) {
            video.pause();
            video.style.height = "0%";
            video.style.width = "0%";
            if (document.fullscreenElement) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            }
            console.log("Video paused and hidden"); 
        } else {
            console.log("Video was already paused when clicked"); 
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log("Video element not found");
}

